# Prepopulate the label after saving data to file

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm saving the data to a text file using the following code, however, when I run the code next time, labels should prepopulate the data which I have saved the previous time. What functionality from Tkinter can be used? Edits in the code are welcome. Looking for favorable support.

```
from tkinter import * 

def save_info():
    firstname_info = firstname.get()
    lastname_info = lastname.get()
    age_info = age.get()
    
    print(firstname_info,lastname_info,age_info)
    
    file = open("user.txt","w")
    
    file.write("Your First Name " + firstname_info)
    
    file.write("\n")
    
    file.write("Your Last Name " + lastname_info)
    
    file.write("\n")
    
    file.write("Your Age " + str(age_info))
    
    file.close()
    
    

app = Tk()

app.geometry("500x500")

app.title("Python File Handling in Forms")

heading = Label(text="Python File Handling in Forms",fg="black",bg="yellow",width="500",height="3",font="10")

heading.pack()

firstname_text = Label(text="FirstName :")
lastname_text = Label(text="LastName :")
age_text = Label(text="Age :")

firstname_text.place(x=15,y=70)
lastname_text.place(x=15,y=140)
age_text.place(x=15,y=210)

firstname = StringVar()
lastname = StringVar()
age = IntVar()

first_name_entry = Entry(textvariable=firstname,width="30")
last_name_entry = Entry(textvariable=lastname,width="30")
age_entry = Entry(textvariable=age,width="30")

first_name_entry.place(x=15,y=100)
last_name_entry.place(x=15,y=180)
age_entry.place(x=15,y=240)

button = Button(app,text="Submit Data",command=save_info,width="30",height="2",bg="grey")

button.place(x=15,y=290)


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential method below

```
def open_info():
    try:
        with open("user.txt","r") as file:
            for line in file:
                if "First Name" in line:
                    firstname.set(line.split("Name ")[1])
                elif "Last Name" in line:
                    lastname.set(line.split("Name ")[1])
                elif "Age" in line:
                    age.set(line.split("Age ")[1])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
```

This function is called using a tkinter method called `after_idle` which I've placed just before `mainloop()`. `after_idle` will call a function once the GUI is loaded.

```
app.after_idle(open_info)
```

Some notes:

- I've used the `with` keyword to open the file since it will automatically close the file afterwards too. You should probably use this in your save function too.
- This method isn't hugely robust for reading your text file but since the file is fairly simple at the moment it does the job. It looks to see if the line contains one of the field names and if it does, splits the line in two and uses the second part as the value you want to enter in to the boxes.
- The `FileNotFoundError` will deal with the initial scenario where the file does not exist and just report an error rather than crashing the program.
- The values are populated to the fields using the `set` method (just the reverse of the `get` method you used)

A more robust method for storing the data, would be to use a machine friendly file format such as JSON which would output to the file looking something like this

```
{"name": "Me", "age": "99"}
```

This can be read/written using the python built in module `json`.